# Does more motors = more regen?

Tags: regenerative

If you have a car with multiple (2-3) motors that are capable of regen braking, do you get more energy recovery than if you have just one motor?

Comment: No, because you still only have one car you're stopping. It's the entire moving car that has the kinetic energy you want to recover. It might even be worse since you might be running the motors out of their mot efficient range.

Comment: @DKNguyen the additional motor can be very big, thus storing great kinetic energy.

Comment: @TQQQ No. You either drive the car with one really big motor or multiple smaller ones. So it more or less equals out. You might as well argue that you should load up your car with cargo so there is more kinetic energy for you to recover.

Comment: That's exactly what i am arguing. It's an anecdotal case of regeneration, but actually there is somewhere an electric mine truck that drives without recharge like that. The ore it takes down from the hill charges it enough to get back up.

Comment: @TQQQ That's not an apples to apples comparison because that cargo is part of the job the vehicle has to do. It's not there both ways of the trips as an extra motor would be. And you're not actually recovering energy as much as you're adding it to the vehicle in the form of the gravitational potential of the cargo at the hilltop.  A designer doesn't go "*We have one motor that can move this car on its own. Let's use two of them for the regen.*" The scenario would be more like "*Should I use one large motor or multiple smaller motors*". I am not sure what is difficult to understand about this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the limiting factors are.

The maximum braking power is limited by all of ...

- the adhesion with the road multiplied by the speed
- the amount of mechanical power the motor/motors can convert
- the amount of electrical power the regen system can handle
- the charge power the batteries can handle

If your car has a single motor, and that is the lowest power in that chain, then yes, increasing the power of the motor by either doubling them up, or fitting a larger motor, will give you more stopping power. Conversely, if one of the others is limiting, then increasing the total motor power will not help.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Or, more accurately: it depends.

You have vehicle of a set mass. It is traveling at a set speed. If therefore has an amount of kinetic energy. This is half the mass times the velocity squared (kenetic energy formula). This is fixed.

Due to conservation of energy the most “regen” you can get out is the half the mass times the velocity squared, minus efficiency losses. The only way that adding another motor will give you more energy will be the increased mass they’ll give your vehicle.

And now to explain why the real answer is “depends”. In the real world, an electric vehicle can scavenge energy by using the drive motor as a brake. However, this is limited by various things, the biggest ones are: motor power (the motor can only work so hard, this works in both directions) the controller capability (the motor controller is limited in power as well) and the energy store (energy stores can only be charged up at a maximum value).

Energy stores, in EVs this is usually batteries, are rarely symmetric, you can discharge a battery a lot faster than you can charge it up. Li-ion batteries often quote 10C discharge, by only 1C charge rate. This limits the amount of energy you can pull out of regen as you need to stick it somewhere for it to be useful. This can be overcome by getting a higher rated battery, which also tend to be bigger, more expensive etc. But it is possible to solve this.

The controller decides where the power goes: pushing into the motor to accelerate, pulling from the motor when slowing down. Like the battery, this can overcome by making a more capable and expensive controller. You’ll probably have to increase the cooling as well to handle the increased losses from the increase power.

And then the motor, which is of finite power, so can only pull so much power out during regen. Like the battery and controller, this can overcome by getting a more powerful and expensive motor. Or, as suggested in the question, by putting in another motor. You’ll probably have to increase the cooling as well. The most violent non-crash event a vehicle undergoes is braking. Cars stop a lot faster than they accelerate. To get a motor which can pull all the kinetic energy out quickly enough to pass modern road safety requirements will be hard, but possible.

So, to answer the question: if you want to increase energy from regen and you have a controller and energy store than can handle the power, and you used to be wasting energy into mechanical breaking, then yes, you could, with enough design effort, get more regen out of the system if you add another motor.